# how to send email in wordpress not using plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am new developer in wordpress. I wanna send email not using plugin . i use function wp_mail as shown below:

```
wp_mail('myname@yahoo.com', 'subject', 'message', $headers);
```

when i use yahoo email myname@yahoo.com i can send 'subject,messege' to my yahoo account. but when i use gmail email xxx@gmail.com  i can't  send 'subject,messege' to my gmail account.why can not send with gmail account? pleas help me !

Comment: you need to show the code you are using. Headers and everything.

Answer (score 1):

As you have problem with only Gmail we can infer that it is not the problem with 'sending' but with 'receiving'. Something is blocking your mail at the receiving end. Following things can be done to ensure better receiption.

1. Use a real address. Dafult is  `wordpress@yourdomain.com`. This can be filtered with [wp_mail_from](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from).
2. Use SMTP to send email. You can do this with [phpmailer_init](http://www.butlerblog.com/2013/12/12/easy-smtp-email-settings-for-wordpress/) action.
3. Disable headers.
4. Contact hosting providers and confirm that your server is not blacklisted by Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

If you used wp_mail to send your message, without a plugin, this means you didn't use Google's SMTP server. And you're wondering why you didn't receive it at your gmail account? Because you basically forged your from address. Of course Google rejected your email.

The only way to get that to work is to use *authentication* when sending your mail. That means connecting to the smtp.gmail.com server and in 2015 that means using OAuth 2.0 unless you want to deal with another can of worms.

Check out [Postman SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) for sending mail in WordPress.

Here's some reading for you to do: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.no/2014/10/updates-on-authentication-for-gmail.html